# MappingJacksonValue in ResponseEntity returns partial response in Unit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to write a unit test for a GET controller which responds with `ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>`. While debugging I can see in the return statement that the data are as expected but in my test the response's content contains only a partial result. My controller works as expected if tested with Postman.

My class test is annotated with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
```

The call to the controller is this:

```
MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(get("/my-get/v1/number")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andReturn().getResponse();
```

Comment: can you post the test case code?

Comment: I have updated the call to the controller.

Comment: i guess test case is correct all you need to do is
String data = response.getContentAsString();
your response will be there in data

Comment: You are correct this is what I am doing but the response is partial from what I see in the return of the controller.